# matplotlib c++ how to plot 3d objects

Tags: c++, matplotlib, plot

In my code I have taken the 3D coordinates of 2 points and made 3 vector for the x, y, and z coordinates respectively and I want to plot a line in 3D space. I believe in python you have to add subplots to make it 3d and in the c++ wrapper you just input the 3 vectors? There is a surprising lack of instruction on how to plot single points or lines in 3D for the c++ Matplotlib. Does anyone know if there is a necessary plot setup and if there are specific plotting commands for 3D?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, matplotlib-cpp only supports plot_surface for 3D plots.

Since matplotlib-cpp is outdated (recent update was several years ago) and lacks many functionality, I strongly suggest to use [matplotplusplus](https://alandefreitas.github.io/matplotplusplus/). matplot++ uses vector<double> as input variables for line plots and vector<vector<double>> for surface plots.

I am personally trying to implement MATLAB / Python-NUMPY based code into c++ code, and I really find matplot++ heplful. You will be able to find many examples from their git [repository](https://github.com/Cryoris/matplotlib-cpp/tree/master/examples). But if you need a little more, [here](https://github.com/dannylhong/data-driven-cpp/tree/main/CH01) are some examples from my personal project.