# The matplotlibcpp shows an error when I run an example

Tags: matplotlib

Today when I ran an example in matplotlibcpp, I had the following error:

> **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
> what(): No axis Aborted**

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS. The code from the matplotlibcpp examples is the following

```
#include "../matplotlibcpp.h"

#include <cmath>

namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> x, y, z;
    for (double i = -5; i <= 5;  i += 0.25) {
        std::vector<double> x_row, y_row, z_row;
        for (double j = -5; j <= 5; j += 0.25) {
            x_row.push_back(i);
            y_row.push_back(j);
            z_row.push_back(::std::sin(::std::hypot(i, j)));
        }
        x.push_back(x_row);
        y.push_back(y_row);
        z.push_back(z_row);
    }

    plt::plot_surface(x, y, z);
    plt::show();
}
```

I checked matplotlibcpp.h and found

> **if (!axis) throw std::runtime_error("No axis");**

in line 567. I don't know what the problem is. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No c++ problem definitely. Refer to the mathplotlib documentation regarding this.

Comment: I think the problem is matplotlib.h but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: No, that's a runtime error, not a compilation problem. You're using the API wrong apparently.

Comment: So the problem is from my system?

Comment: I can run other examples except this and line3d.cpp.

Comment: Strongly related: [matplotlib c++ how to plot 3d objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72664847/matplotlib-c-how-to-plot-3d-objects)